# Generate a 4D array using random numbers in java?

Tags: java, arrays, oop

Main Class

```
public class Lab6Class {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Die die = new Die();
        int random = 1;
        System.out.println("Your lucky number is: ");
        
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j<4;j++) {
                System.out.print(die.roll(random));
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Die Class

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Die {
int numFaces=6;

public int roll(int random){
    int result;
    Random rand = new Random();
    result = rand.nextInt(6)+1;
    return result;  
    }
}
```

My only issue is how to generate 4D number given in this program.  I mean at least I attempted to generate number but not in 4D format.

Comment: Your own question's title of "4D array" should point you in the right direction. I don't the see usage of an array anywhere.

Comment: What do the terms`4D number`, `4D format` mean? I guess they're related to the 4D array in your question title, but it's not completely clear.

Comment: int fourDim[][][][] = new int[3][4][5][6]; That line creats a four-dimensional array. Do you have any other meaning?

Comment: Excuse me? I'm new to OOP. Please don't judge me by my incompetence in producing a 4D array?

Comment: @f1sh That's my qn because it's either produce a matrix of 4x4 array or just 4 numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume `4D number` have 4-components. For example:

```
eg: 4D_number = [1,2,3,4] = [d1,d2,d3,d4]
```

Code:

```
public class Lab6Class {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Die die = new Die();
    int random = 1;
    System.out.println("Your lucky number is: ");

    Num4D n4d = new Lab6Class().new Num4D(die.roll(random),die.roll(random),die.roll(random),die.roll(random)); 
    //full number       
    System.out.println(n4d);
    //per component
    System.out.println("n4d_d1="+n4d.d1);
    }
    //inner class
    class Num4D
    {
        public int d1,d2,d3,d4;
        public Num4D(int d1,int d2, int d3, int d4)
        {
           this.d1 = d1;
           this.d2 = d2;
           this.d3 = d3;
           this.d4 = d4;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return "4DNumber=["+d1+","+d2+","+d3+","+d4+"]";
        }
     }
}
```

Output:

```
Your lucky number is: 
4DNumber=[5,2,5,3] 
n4d_d1=5
```

Also you have to know what exactly is expected `4D_Number` or `4D_array` (not the same as representation).

Eg: `4DNumber=[5,2,5,3]` and `4DArray on [0][0][0][0]=oneValue_maybe_4DNumber` 

`Num4D arr[][][][] = new Num4D[2][3][4][5]; \\and need to add 2x3x4x5->Num4D`

`... arr[0][0][0][0] = num4d_1 ... etc`

Reformulate. This code is produce a `4D_Number` as your main concern. But the usage is entirely up to you (fill an array component with as title suggest or what ever it's needed).